# Why does connecting an Android USB-C to Windows 10 USB-C take 10-30 seconds to get recognized by the system?

Tags: windows-10, android, usb-c

I have an Android phone with a USB-C port. My new Windows 10 desktop computer also has a USB-C port.

My old cables plugged into my phone and computer (Via a USB-A port just fine, and everything behaves just as I expect. Just like my last computer, my phone gets recognized by the computer in less than a second (I hear a noise on the computer once it's connected.

To get faster data transfer rates and charging rate, I decided to get a USB-C to USB-C cable. When I plug in the phone using USB-C to USB-C, it takes 10-30 seconds to get recognized by the computer (and the phone according to the new "Charging Rapidly" message on the lock screen).

Why does it take so long? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

I tried to do a little research online, and the closest thing I could find was to check with something about Bluetooth settings, but as best as I can tell, my new computer doesn't have Bluetooth.

Comment: Could be some difficulty in Power Delivery negotiations, some timeouts due to not very matched profiles... Did you try any other less sophisticated Type-C devices, like a flash drive? Does it also take that long?

Comment: @Ale..chenski That's good enough to be an answer. I haven't tested it yet, so I'm not sure it's the accepted answer yet, but it's worth at least an answer upvote.